# how to get the properties of a datasource in WAS 6.1

Tags: java

I am migrating an app from WAS4 to WAS6.1

A piece of code is as follows:

```
javax.naming.Context ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource)ctx.lookup(JNDI_NAME);                       
dsvalue_data   = new Hashtable(); 
confvalue_data = new Hashtable();

// Parse the datasource string and get the properties
// writeInfo will return the name of the datasource and will populate the
// dsvalue_data and confvalue_data hashtables with datasource and 
// connection pool properties

String tableHeader = writeInfo(ds.toString());

aResultHandler.addObject(CV_ABOUT_DESC,tableHeader);
aResultHandler.addObject(CV_ABOUT_PAGE,dsvalue_data);
.....
.....
```

The problem is in WAS6.1, this `ds.toString()` does not give the human readable properties of the datasource

It just gives the object name (like `com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@a21fg7`) when i tried to print.

what should I do to get and print all the properties of the datasource?

Answer (score 1):

After obtaining your datasource `ds`, you can get database information like this:

```
DatabaseMetaData md = ds.getConnection().getMetaData();
```

There are tons of methods to be used, you can get a list from [official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html).

Answer (score 0):

What is your main objective? DataSource as such doesn't expose the properties your are looking for. May be you are confused by the aResultHandler API.

I will start with saying that you need to get rid of the aResultHandler API or refactor it to make use of DataSource.

If you doesn't have that option for whatever insane reason below is another option. Not sure if this works.

Depending upon the toString() was a bad choice made and hence your in this trouble. I suggest you try to cast the DataSource returned from JNDI lookup to WAS implementation class (do ds.getClass() to see what is the actual impl class) and see if these properties are exposed in some way.

Answer (score 0):

@Pangea

In Was4,ds.toString() gives the details of the datasource in a readable format

which is then formatted to display the properties..like

```
 errorMap   =  null 
 logOrphan   =  false 
 connTimeout   =  180 
 TransactionBranchesLooselyCoupled  =  false 
 resetReadOnly   =  false 
 maxConnectionPoolSize   =  10 
 autoConnectionCleanupDisabled   =  false 
 minConnectionPoolSize   =  1 
 secureXACredential   =  false 
 surgeThreshold   =  -1 
 informixLockModeWait   =  0 
 dataBaseVersion   =  0 
 validationSQL   =  null 
 oracleStmtCacheSize   =  0 
 orphanTimeout   =  1800 
 stuckThreshold   =  -1 
 surgeTime   =  20 
 stuckTime   =  30 
 diagOptions   =  0 
 connectionValidation   =  false 
 maxStatementCacheSize   =  10 
 stuckTimerTime   =  5 
 idleTimeout   =  1800
```

Comment: do not post followup questions as a separate post. it should be a comment. anyways updated my post with more info.